# Up Casting Using References Instead Of Pointers

Tags: c++, oop, casting, upcasting

I wonder if the following up-casting is valid? And if yes, is it possible to down-cast in the same way?

```
class A {
public:
    A(){ cout << "A constructor\n";};
    A(const A& a){ cout << "A copy constructor\n"; };
};


class B : public A {
public:
    B(){ cout << "B constructor\n";};
    B(const B& b){ cout << "B copy constructor\n"; };
};

int main(){

    B* b = new B;
    cout << "--------\n";
    A& a = *b;

    return 0;
}
```

I got no output from doing `A& a = *b;`, does this mean that doing this is equivalent to up-casting?

Comment: There are no casts in this code. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Comment: You should be able to test this theory yourself, simply by compiling it. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: a reference is a non-nullable const pointer, whenever a pointer would work a reference would work too, except for a nullpointer, there is no null-reference.

Comment: @AhmedWaleed There is only one default constructor called in your code.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik 
I tried to write an explicit constructor and copy constructor with couts in body to test whether either is called, but i got empty console.

Comment: You do realize that a constructor only gets called when a new object gets, well, constructed? There's only one object that gets constructed, in the shown code. So, you should expect to see at least that message.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have updated the code in the question. I meant that i got no output from doing `A& a = *b;`

Comment: Why do you expect to get output from `A& a = *b;`?  A reference is a non-nullable, non-rebind-able *alias*.  Giving another name for the same object.  (And only extends the lifetime of a temporary is specific circumstances.)

Comment: @Eljay. I deduced that if no new construction is made then, doing this is equivalent of doing a cast

Comment: It is not the equivalent of doing a cast.  It is the equivalent of having another identifier name that refers to the same object.

Comment: @Eljay, If the derived class has a  data member say x, you cannot access it after doing `A& a = *b;`

Comment: @AhmedWaleed No, not directly but so what? `A& a = *b;` just makes a reference to `*b`. It doesn't construct an`A`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, no construction is made. But the side effect from doing this line `A& a = *b;` is the same effect of doing an up cast.

Comment: @PeteBecker but writing code like this makes an effect similar to the effect of doing up cast (like you cannot access derived class exclusive data members)

Comment: @AhmedWaleed — as you well know, your original question, to which I replied, asked if “this up cast” is valid. Again; there is no cast in your code (despite the use of “up cast” in your title). You’re asking whether the **conversion** is valid.

Comment: Sure you can, but you'll need to use a cast.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, the term "cast" is imprecise and I used that term due to the similarity of result I got by doing this. Anyway thank you!

Comment: @AhmedWaleed -- the term "cast" has an exact meaning. Some people don't know that, and use it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

`A& a = *b;` behaves exactly in the same way that `A* a = b;` would, i.e. `a` will be a reference bound to the `A` base class subobject of the `B` object or a pointer to the same subobject, respectively. It technically does however not involve any conversion (which is what you erroneously call a "cast"), instead it is just reference initialization.

But neither of these initializations ever have any side effects, nor could they ever involve creation of a new object, a constructor call or any other function call.

Downcasts are possible in the exact same way as well and also have no side effects:

```
B* b2 = static_cast<B*>(a);
```

if `a` is a `A*` or

```
B& b = static_cast<B&>(a);
```

if `a` is a `A&`. (Of course both have undefined behavior if the `A` object referred to by the right-hand side isn't actually a base class subobject of an `B` object.)

Comment: "It technically does however not involve any implicit conversion" -- not completely true -- it does an implicit conversion of `B&` to `A&`, which can never have side effects (and in this case doesn't even change the pointer, as `A` is the first and only base class of `B`)

Comment: @ChrisDodd No, that's precisely the technicality I mean. This isn't an _implicit conversion_ because it is none of the conversions listed in https://eel.is/c++draft/conv. Instead it is behavior that is explicitly specified for reference initialization, e.g. in https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5.1.sentence-1: "_(or, in either case, to the appropriate base class subobject of the object)_".

Comment: @ChrisDodd Or at least it isn't a conversion in the sense of individual standard conversions or user-defined conversions. The use of the term "implicit conversion" is a bit unclear. So I removed it from my answer.

Comment: Its not a *standard conversion* -- it is a *reference binding* conversion, as defined in [eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.ref](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.ref).  But yes, the precise terminology of 'conversion' vs 'impllicit conversion' vs 'standard conversion' vs 'cast' is unclear.

Comment: The only definition I can find for *implicit conversion* is in [eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics), which contradicts itself (first saying that it is a standard conversion, then saying it is "governed by the rules for initialization of an object or reference by a single expression")

Comment: @ChrisDodd [over.ics.ref] and [over.best.ics] are only relevant to overload resolution and are only concerned with _implicit conversion sequences_ and their ranking, not actual conversions in the sense of e.g. [conv]. _Implicit conversion sequence_ is also distinct from the term _implicit conversion_ which is (at least somewhat) defined by https://eel.is/c++draft/expr#conv.general-3 and applies if some other part of the standard demands something to be "implicitly converted".

Comment: @user17732522 I feel like it is more than simple reference initialization as the reference must be binded to the appropriate subobject so i feel like the right hand side must be converted or casted implicitly to match the left hand side type. This non trivial operation what made call it casting

Comment: @user17732522 but from the conversation here I am now convinced that we should never call it a cast. And this type of initialization is handled smartly by the compiler to get a reference of the matching subobject type. Correct me if any misunderstanding

Comment: @AhmedWaleed The word "cast" refers to a specific syntax that is intended to explicitly cause a conversion, such as `static_cast<T>(...)` or `(T)...`. A conversion can be implicit or explicit, with the latter being a cast. The discussion we have in the comments is about some specific terminology used in the standard. It is not really important. Call it an implicit conversion if you want. The difference between that and what it technically is ("_reference binding_") is minuscule and will only matter if you want to language-lawyer about small details in the standard's wording.